# git status only file names separated for spaces

Tags: git, git-status

Is it possible to `git status` to return in one line all paths of files modified and separated with spaces? if its possible, How I do this?

I tried:

```
git status --porcelain | sed -e 's!.*/!!'^C'
```

But this command does not return the changed files in one line.

Comment: *Why* do you want this?  This smells like an XY problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: I want to create a script to deploy the changed files, the command to deploy files needs the file's paths and if have more files separate the files with a space

Comment: Normally you would deploy committed files, not work-tree-modified files.  Either way, however, the tool to use is not `git status` but rather some variant of `git diff` (`git diff-index`, `git diff-files`, etc) with `--name-only` or `--name-status` and possibly `-z`.  Using `-z` and piping to `xargs` might be the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page, `git status -z` will separate entries with NUL instead of LF, which should put everything on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git status | grep modified: | awk '{printf "%s ",$3} END {print ""}'
```

This for modified files, for new files just pass the argument to grep.